# How to run a function first before updating the array in react JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, async-await, promise

```
const handleItinerary = (e, type) => {
        
        var index = parseInt(e.target.name);
        let arr = [...itinerary];
        
        if (type === "imageUrl") {
            
            const date = new Date().getTime();
            const storageRef = ref(storage, `${date}`);

            uploadBytes(storageRef, e.target.files[0]).then((snapshot) => {
                
                getDownloadURL(storageRef).then((downloadURL) => {
                    arr[index]["imageUrl"] = downloadURL;
                    
                });
            });
                
        }
            

        setitinerary(arr);

    }
```

In the above code I am trying to upload an image in firebase storage using uploadBytes function and after uploading the image I get the downloadURL where image is stored, I want to put its value in arr[index]["imageUrl"], but the arr[index]["imageUrl"] is getting updated first before getting the downloadURL and I am getting error that downloadURL is undefined, so how to resolve this issue?
I am using react 18 and firebase version 9.

Answer (score 0):

When using `then()` to run code in response to an asynchronous operation being completed, any code that needs to run upon completion has to be **inside** that `then()` callback.

So

```
const handleItinerary = (e, type) => {
    var index = parseInt(e.target.name);
    let arr = [...itinerary];
    
    if (type === "imageUrl") {
        const date = new Date().getTime();
        const storageRef = ref(storage, `${date}`);

        uploadBytes(storageRef, e.target.files[0]).then((snapshot) => {
            getDownloadURL(storageRef).then((downloadURL) => {
                arr[index]["imageUrl"] = downloadURL;
                setitinerary(arr);                    
            });
        });                
    }
}
```

---

To make this a bit more familiar, you can mark the `` as `async` and use `await` inside it:

```
const handleItinerary = async (e, type) => {
    var index = parseInt(e.target.name);
    let arr = [...itinerary];
    
    if (type === "imageUrl") {
        const date = new Date().getTime();
        const storageRef = ref(storage, `${date}`);

        const snapshot = await uploadBytes(storageRef, e.target.files[0]);
        const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
        arr[index]["imageUrl"] = downloadURL;
        setitinerary(arr);                    
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't change anything about the actual behavior and all asynchronous calls are still executed asynchronously. It is merely a more familiar way to write the code.

---

If you have a list of images to upload, be sure to either [use `for of` instead of `forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop) or `Promise.all` to detect when all asynchronous operations are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the code that updates the `arr[index]["imageUrl"]` value inside the `then` block where you retrieve the `downloadURL`. This will ensure that the `arr[index]["imageUrl"]` value is only updated after the `downloadURL` has been retrieved.

```
const handleItinerary = (e, type) => {
  var index = parseInt(e.target.name);
  let arr = [...itinerary];

  if (type === "imageUrl") {
    const date = new Date().getTime();
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `${date}`);

    uploadBytes(storageRef, e.target.files[0]).then((snapshot) => {
      getDownloadURL(storageRef).then((downloadURL) => {
        arr[index]["imageUrl"] = downloadURL;
        setitinerary(arr);
      });
    });
  }
}
```